# Create an array with same structure as pg_fetch_all()

Tags: php, arrays

I need to recreate an array that has the same structure as the `pg_fetch_all()` function but I cannot understand the concept:

I'm trying to create it by looping through a querystring and when the key of the querystring matches then add the values:

This is the way I'm trying but it only stores the last values of my for loop:

```
foreach($_REQUEST as $key => $x) {
    if(strpos($key,"tldid_loc_") !== false) {
        $currlocation = $x; 
    }

    if(strpos($key,"tldid_action_") !== false) {
        $arr_new_trip["tldlocation"] = $currlocation;
        $arr_new_trip["tldaction"] = $x;
    }
}
```

What I need is a structure that replicates a DB table like:

```
tldlocation|tldaction
a          | b
c          | d
e          | f
```

Query string output with `var_dump($_REQUEST)`:

```
array(17) { ["tripid"]=> string(2) "50" ["tldid_loc_1"]=> string(1) "1" ["tldid_action_494"]=> string(12) "LOADING DATE" ["tldid_action_495"]=> string(14) "DEPARTURE DATE" ["tldid_loc_3"]=> string(1) "3" ["tldid_action_496"]=> string(12) "ARRIVAL DATE" ["tldid_action_497"]=> string(14) "DEPARTURE DATE" ["tldid_loc_6"]=> string(1) "6" ["tldid_action_499"]=> string(15) "OFFLOADING DATE" ["tldid_action_500"]=> string(14) "DEPARTURE DATE" ["tldid_action_498"]=> string(12) "ARRIVAL DATE" ["tldid_loc_8"]=> string(1) "8" ["tldid_action_501"]=> string(12) "ARRIVAL DATE" ["tldid_action_502"]=> string(14) "DEPARTURE DATE" ["tldid_loc_7"]=> string(1) "7" ["tldid_action_503"]=> string(12) "ARRIVAL DATE" ["tldid_action_504"]=> string(15) "OFFLOADING DATE" }
```

When I loop through this array, if I find `tldid_loc_XXX` I store that value, then the next values (tldid_action_XXX) are my values.

The structure for the array I am looking for is (looking at the first values):

```
tldlocation|tldaction
1          |LOADING DATE
1          |DEPARTURE DATE
3          |LOADING DATE
3          |DEPARTURE DATE
```

and so on.

Comment: Please show the content of `$_REQUEST` and the desired output (in array form).

Comment: Maybe what you want is [parse_str()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)?

Comment: How do I add a key with `parse_str()` my keys do not come from the query string, only the values

Comment: Ah, hard to tell from your original post.  No, you can't define the keys with that.